# Linq query to take the value from Array with matching sub string value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string - **`filterArg`** and array of string - **`arrayColDef`** as shown in below code. I am trying to split the string **`filterArg`** by **`|~|`** and trying to get the value from **`filterArg`** by matching **`arrayColDef`** value.
Can any one let me know how to get the value ***ToDo*** commented in the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            string filterArg = "ZipCode=2130|~|ZipPlace=KNAPPER";
            string[] arrayColDef = { "ZipCode", "Space", "ZipPlace" };

            foreach (var item in arrayColDef)
            {
                var key = item;
                var value = filterArg.Split(new string[] { "|~|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);//TODO: here value should hold = 2130 for first itteration
                ht.Add(item, value);
            }

        }
```

Comment: `filterArg.Split(...).FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(key + "="))`? What have you tried? Can you explain properly, in full sentences, in your question (and not in comments) what that line should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get complicated iterating over `arrayColDef`, it's easier to iterate through splited string and extract the values.
You can do something like below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    string filterArg = "ZipCode=2130|~|ZipPlace=KNAPPER";
    string[] arrayColDef = { "ZipCode", "Space", "ZipPlace" };

    var properties = filterArg.Split(new string[] { "|~|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var nameValue = property.Split(arrayColDef, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var item = property.Split('=').First(); // get key
        var value = nameValue.First().TrimStart('='); // get value
        ht.Add(item, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you that worked. Your solution is somple and easy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
string filterArg = "ZipCode=2130|~|ZipPlace=KNAPPER";
string[] arrayColDef = { "ZipCode", "Space", "ZipPlace" };
var filterArr = filterArg.Split(new string[] { "|~|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x.Split('='));
foreach (var item in arrayColDef)
{
    var key = item;
    var v = filterArr.FirstOrDefault(x => x[0] == item);
    if (v != null&&v.Length>1)
    {
        ht.Add(item, v[1]);
    }
}

foreach (var key in ht.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value:{1}", key, ht[key]);
}
```

`Space` has been ignored

Answer (score 0):

The filter split in

```
var value = filterArg.Split(new string[] { "|~|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);//TODO: here value should hold = 2130 for first itteration
```

returns an array. You can get the final value by filtering and replacing with linq:

```
string finalValue = value.Where(m => m.Contains(item)).Select(m => m.Replace(item+"=","")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The value, then, is in finalValue variable.

Greetings